# Evaluation of the Chat Event (Session 1)

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, chat-event

### Summary

All in all, this chat session was a great pleasure. I found the atmosphere amicable and yet productive, and it was a lot of fun to see the number of unanswered questions dwindle away. Thank you to everybody who participated in this event, I hope that even more people will participate next time!

### Categorization

The main goal of this preliminary session was to answer the easy questions straight away and categorize the remaining ones. The categories most used were:

- **Medium:** Requires light research to answer the question.
- **Vote:** As the question stands, it is not fit for this site. The community is required to make a decision by vote whether it should be closed or migrated.
- **Comment Answer:** There was a good answer presented in the comments to the question. The author of the comment was pinged and asked to develop a full answer from the comment.

And last but not least:

- **Answered:** The question has been answered by the auditor and requires votes to count. These votes were provided by the fellow auditors.

### Real-Time Spreadsheet

In order to work together efficiently, I set up a Google Spreadsheet that was used to communicate about questions with other auditors in real time, using a number code for the status of the question. I have already frozen the sheet for the first session and prepared a sheet for the next session, containing all unfinished questions that will have to be tended to. You can find the sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amb7PQuODxg_dDJqRzhoUDFvMDJlWTBmSUptS0xqTWc&usp=sharing).

In my opinion the spreadsheet is a good tool, well-suited for this purpose, and should continue to be used in the future.

### Results

In total, 49 questions were assessed. Of these 49 questions, 20 have gotten up-voted answers or were closed/migrated. The remainder is categorized and still up for voting. You can find more detail in the figure below:

[image: Pie Chart summarizing the results of the first chat session]

### To-Do for the next session

At the start of the next session, somebody should be tasked with the following: Checking the status of the questions that are in the list. If the status has changed, this person will have to indicate the change in the spreadsheet, so the others can react. I suggest only one person do this (or two, one from the top, the other from the bottom) as to minimize the risk of confusion.

### Acknowledgements

This event wouldn't have been possible without the dedication of @ManishEarth, @jonsca and @LordStryker. Thank you for your participation and engagement in this community!

Comment: Great post! I'd like to make it clear to the others that this was not the planned session -- it was a small  "preliminary session" planned by @tschoppi for himself which sort of became bigger -- somehow :)

Comment: Hmm, there were a couple of 1.5 questions (easy, just that I didn't have the time to answer at the moment) -- what happened to them? Did you mark them as yellow? I don't mind volunteering for doing the cleanup before the session (could you modify the settings so that I can edit the locked doc?)

Comment: Thank you for the acknowledgement, but as @ManishEarth mentioned, this session was largely your brainchild, so thank *you*!

Comment: @ManishEarth I never saw any of the 1.5 questions, actually... But sure, I'll unlock it for the time being.
But note that I've copied all the relevant entries to the Sheet labelled "Session 2 - ??"

Comment: @tschoppi Yeah, saw the other sheet before, but got confused :)

Comment: I think its pretty cool how the "Unanswered" %-age under site stats jumped a few points during this event (it was below 84 and now its sitting at 86%).

Comment: Wow, I would like to participate the next one how can I be informed?

Comment: Hmmm. Check meta regularly? And usually a chat event notice gets posted by a moderator. For optimal participation you may also start a new meta post and propose some times :)