# Scheduling of Chat Session 3

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, chat-event

So I've been asked to start coordinate the third chat session, in which we'd attack the large (but slowly dwindling) number of unanswered questions on this site.

If you don't know what this is all about, maybe check out the [original post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342/chat-event-to-deal-with-unanswered-questions) where the outlines were laid and [my write-up](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/evaluation-of-the-chat-event-session-1) of the first session for an idea about what we're trying to accomplish.

To facilitate the scheduling and finding one common denominating date, I've set up a [doodle](http://doodle.com/mibqkbyfmm79ez2u). Go to the following link and enter when you're available. I will then choose the date where the most people are available and post the date here as an answer.

The doodle: http://doodle.com/mibqkbyfmm79ez2u

---

**EDIT:** I've been pretty busy in the recent couple of days and haven't really had much time for this side project. I've therefore expanded the scope of the doodle to incorporate more of this month. Hopefully we'll find a good date (please update your choices) for everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next date is April 23, a Wednesday.

I will be around at about 5.00 pm UTC time, and hope to see as many faces (nicknames) as possible!

Comment: That is 2am LOT for me :(

Comment: @Martin Sorry, these times are adjusted for Europe and USA. Feel free to initiate such an answering session by yourself, it's not that only I am allowed to do it :)

Comment: That is completely okay... Have fun and be productive ;) Just wanted to let you know why I am not being able to...